# Why won't this print, when I type in a keyword?

Tags: python

```
`print"Welcome to Caleb's login script!"
 loop = 'true'
 while(loop == 'true'):
username = raw_input("Username Please")
password= raw_input("Password Please")
if(username == "Caleb" and password == "Lamps320"):
 print 'Logged in as ' + username
 loop = 'false'
 loop1 = 'true'
 while(loop1 == 'true'):
     command = raw_input(username + " >> ")
     if(command == "exit" or command == "Exit"):
        break
        if(command == "Passwords" or command == "passwords"):
          print"passwords"

else: 
    print 'Invalid Username/password! Please try again.'
```

I want it to print passwords when I type "Passwords or passwords" it will say  'password'. But when I try and run it and log in and type in passwords or Passwords it will not work. Can somebody help me?
  The code is supposed to be a login system to access something. But when I type in the keyword (password) it just returns the command prompt. Note: I used Python2.7.3 (Also I can't get the python code to work with the code indent.

--For those just seeing this, I apologize! This was done very badly and when I was very immature! I have learned a lot since this post. Thanks to the person who tried to help old me!

Comment: Please fix your indentation. In Python, this is significant. As it is currently displayed the script won't run.

Comment: I tried. I'll edit it real quick.

Comment: Caleb, the easiest way is to delete the code block and paste it directly from your code editor. Then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K. The editor will indent your block uniformly by four spaces.

Comment: No. And depending on indentation level of "loop = 'false'" and everything after that your code will show different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is inconsistently indented. It does what you say it does when that is fixed.

```
print"Welcome to Caleb's login script!"
loop = 'true'
while(loop == 'true'):
    username = raw_input("Username Please")
    password= raw_input("Password Please")
    if(username == "Caleb" and password == "Lamps320"):
        print 'Logged in as ' + username
        loop = 'false'
        loop1 = 'true'
        while(loop1 == 'true'):
            command = raw_input(username + " >> ")
            if(command == "exit" or command == "Exit"):
                break
            if(command == "Passwords" or command == "passwords"):
                print"passwords"
    else: 
        print 'Invalid Username/password! Please try again.'
```

Depending on how secure this is supposed to be, there are many ways to make it better. Here are a few.

- Compare the password to a hash instead of the actual password so your password isn't in plaintext inside the file. See, for example, [PyBcrypt project](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-bcrypt/)
- No 'true' and 'false' constants. Python already has `True` and `False` for this purpose, they are the boolean type.